# Tabula: Entire table stored in a single cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pdf, tabula

I would like to read tables from a number of PDFs and consolidate them into a dataframe in a pandas notebook. I tried using tabula to do this but I find that the entire table is stored in [0, 0]. This is a problem since I still want to be able to access individual rows and/or columns from the table. An example of a part of the table that I want to read is:

| Methode | Parameter | Eeneid | Concentratie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SFA | Ureum | mg/l | <6 |
| pH-EC | pH Q | mg/l | 5.4 |
| pH-EC | EC Q | mS/cm | 4.4 |
| pH-EC | Waterstofcarbonaat | mg/l | <6.1 |
| SFA | Ammonium | mg/l | 54.8 |
| SFA | Nitraat | mg/l | 1894 |

I added a few arguments to try and fix this but to no avail. The read function currently stands as:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf(file_path, stream = True,
                                lattice= True,
                                pandas_options= {"header": [0, 1]},
                                guess = False)
```

As an added verification that it is stored in a single cell, I see the entire table when I print df[0] but an error that the index is out of range when I print df[1]. Does anybody know how I can read the table as a table I can still operate on?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide a sample data (image won't help reproduce the issue).

Comment: @AliMassoud Done, I've replaced the image with part of the table in text